# Expression Blend 3 Build Configuration

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, expression-blend

In Visual Studio I can easily control which configuration is built, Debug or Release or something else.  How do I control which configuration is built in Expression Blend 3?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191270/why-isnt-expression-blend-4s-designer-working-whenever-we-use-build-configurati).  I think that Blend 3 and Blend 4 work similarly when it comes to build configuration.